# Issues with first-time boot of OpenELEC on RPi1

Tags: openelec, pi-1

I recently installed OpenELEC onto and SD card for my RPi1, following the instructions on the Distro wiki. Upon inserting and starting the Pi, a screen showing the OpenELEC logo shows for a while then a screen showing the Kodi logo and version (15, isengard).

This is where my issue stands - It doesn't go past this screen. It repeats a cycle of showing this logo then having a small RGB glitch out, then back to the logo.

Do you have any idea why my install isn't working?

Thank you!